# Addition of column to Table ,do i need to generate DBML again?

Tags: sql, linq

Let us say there is two application ,one app use a DB table through stored procedure while other uses the same table through LINQ to sql,

I am adding new column to that table,to fulfill the need of third app using the same table but through stored Procedures.

I know the application with stored procedure won't have any issue .
The question is would i need to generate the DBML file again,or the Second application won't crash.

Please if **yes** why/if **no** why?

Comment: why don't you try? really.

Comment: @IsThatSo because the deployment need to be done at someone else end, and it is not testapp, i cant go for hunch i need to be sure what i am doing.

Comment: and i need to be sure about reason,because they will ask me why you need to change dll of app2 while you was working on app3, or if i go in dark the app2 will break

Comment: then, i don't find it logical to update dbml time for small changes. if the program complains about a mismatch in columns, just create a new small procedure for it.

Comment: as I know: extra columns in DB doesn't causes errors, as you can fill all the attributes in application side. your concern should be filling the attributes.

Comment: @IsThatSo Man i think you are not getting my point or i am not getting you,should i update my question for more explanation or something

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only add a *nullable* column to a table you don't have to regenerate the DBML if you don't need the new column in the application. LINQ-to-SQL will simply generate `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements that don't contain the new column, but that's OK.

Of course this is different if the column has a NOT NULL constraint, *and* no default value. In that case an `INSERT` through LINQ-to-SQL will fail.